# locationManager Delegate not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit

I have included `NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in my info.plst file and my code is like this.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit



class LocationSelectorViewController: UIViewController, 
UISearchBarDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var locationSearchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
var selectedLoc: String?
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didupdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

}
}
```

I think I have nothing wrong but it is keep showing this error

> Cannot Assign value of type "LocationSelectorViewController" to type "CLLocationManagerDelegate?"

Can you tell me where is the Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot Assign value of type "LocationSelectorViewController" to type "CLLocationManagerDelegate?"

Ans :
Your `LocationSelectorViewController` class must adopt and conform to`CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol.

Add the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in your class as shown below.

```
class LocationSelectorViewController: UIViewController, 
UISearchBarDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

instead of

```
 class LocationSelectorViewController: UIViewController, 
UISearchBarDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
```